# Getting the largest and smallest word at a string

Tags: string, julia

when I run this codes the output is (" "," "),however it should be ("I","love")!!!, and there is no errors . what should I do to fix it ??

sen="I love dogs"

```
function Longest_word(sen)
  x=" "

  maxw=" "

  minw=" "

  minl=1

  maxl=length(sen)

  p=0

  for i=1:length(sen)

     if(sen[i]!=" ")
         x=[x[1]...,sen[i]...]
    else
      p=length(x)

      if p<min1

        minl=p
        minw=x
      end

      if p>maxl
        maxl=p
        maxw=x
      end
      x=" "
    end
  end


  return minw,maxw

end
```

Comment: What's your question here?

Comment: Is that ` min1` correct?

Comment: I think you can do better...

Comment: Hi Taghreed. We would like to help you, but you need to be specific with your question: what are you trying to do? what is the behaviour that you expect? and what is not working? In that way we will be in a better position to help you. Please have a look at some other questions to see how they are written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of your code is good, but there are a few mistakes.
You can see what's going wrong by debugging a bit. The easiest way to do this is with `@show`, which prints out the value of variables. When code doesn't work like you expect, this is the first thing to do -- just ask it what it's doing by printing everything out!

E.g. if you put

```
if(sen[i]!=" ")
    x=[x[1]...,sen[i]...]
    @show x
```

and run the function with

```
Longest_word("I love dogs")
```

you will see that it is not doing what you want it to do, which (I believe) is add the ith letter to the string x.

Note that the ith letter accessed like sen[i] is a *character* not a *string*.
You can try converting it to a string with

```
string(sen[i])
```

but this gives a Unicode string, not an ASCII string, in recent versions of Julia.

In fact, it would be better not to iterate over the string using

```
for i in 1:length(sen)
```

but iterate over the *characters* in the string (which will also work if the string is Unicode):

```
for c in sen
```

Then you can initialise the string `x` as

```
x = UTF8String("")
```

and update it with

```
x = string(x, c)
```

Try out some of these possibilities and see if they help.

Also, you have maxl and minl defined wrong initially -- they should be the other way round. Also, the names of the variables are not very helpful for understanding what should happen.  And the strings should be initialised to *empty* strings, `""`, not a string with a space, `" "`.

@daycaster is correct that there seems to be a `min1` that should be `minl`.

*However*, in fact there is an easier way to solve the problem, using the `split` function, which divides a string into words.

Let us know if you still have a problem.

Here is a working version following your idea:

```
function longest_word(sentence)
    x = UTF8String("")

    maxw = ""
    minw = ""

    maxl = 0      # counterintuitive! start the "wrong" way round
    minl = length(sentence)

    for i in 1:length(sentence)          # or:  for c in sentence

        if sentence[i] != ' '            # or:  if c != ' '
            x = string(x, sentence[i])   #  or:  x = string(x, c)

        else

            p = length(x)

            if p < minl
                minl = p
                minw = x
            end

            if p > maxl
                maxl = p
                maxw = x
            end

            x = ""
        end
    end

    return minw, maxw

end
```

Note that this function does not work if the longest word is at the *end* of the string. How could you modify it for this case?

Comment: Nice job! You could encourage the poster to watch some of your cool videos too ... :)

Answer (score 4):

As @David mentioned, another and may be better solution can be achieved by using `split` function:

```
function longest_word(sentence)
  sp=split(sentence)
  len=map(length,sp)
  return (sp[indmin(len)],sp[indmax(len)])
end
```